# programmatically add custom flow layout to UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have a custom flow layout that I want to use for my `UICollectionView`, but I don't know how to do it programmatically.

More details: my `UICollectionView` is a subview in my view controller that conforms to `UICollectionViewDataSource` and `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`protocols.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you init your collection view in codes,pass custom flow layout to `init(frame: CGRect, collectionViewLayout layout: UICollectionViewLayout)`.You can also set `collectionViewLayout` after that.

Comment: How can i set customFlowLayout for section 2 only when i am having 2 section in collectionview?

Answer (score 2):

In objectiveC:

```
UICollectionView *collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] init];

collectionView.collectionViewLayout = YOURCustomLayout;
```

or simply:

```
UICollectionView *collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:YOURFrame collectionViewLayout:YOURCustomLayout];
```

for Swift check @Lumialxk answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think that'll do.

```
override init(collectionViewLayout layout: UICollectionViewLayout) {
    super.init(collectionViewLayout: layout)
    collectionView?.collectionViewLayout = YourCollectionViewLayout()
}
```